# HTML Text Box output webpage value

Tags: html, dynamic, textbox

Effectivily I have a web page text box that I want it to load the value that it outputed when going to a link.

I have a link called www.mydomin.com/number.html

This page just displays a number (lets say it displays 1234).

I then have a another page called show.html.

this page just has a basic html text box.

I want this basic html text box to display the output number at www.mydomin.com/number.html

so this text box should in theory display 1234

I have tried value="www.mydomin.com/number.html" but that just shows the actual link.

Any ideas? Greatly appreciated.

Comment: What determines the value on your `number.html` page? Use that when determining the value for your textbox.

Comment: For the purpose of this example. I have just put 1234 in the number.html

Comment: So the correct solution would be to "just put" 1234 in the box as well.

Comment: HTML alone, can not do this. You have to use server-side scripting (PHP, ASP, etc), or javascript, ajax. There is more than one way of passing that value, too: cookie, session variable, and the like. If you utilize POST/GET data from submitting a form on one page, and passing to the next you'll still need something other than HTML to process that data.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use jQuery AJAX requests if needed (although I agree fully with @Madara's first comment):

```
$.get("number.html",function(data){
   $("#myinput").attr("value", data);
}
```